# how to webscraping use to scrape the data in Inspect elemrnt or view page source

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I tried webscraping in particular website.but I cant get the tag .I see tag in Inspect element and viewpage source also.how to get tag can you please any give me suggestion.

**WebScrapy.py**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import html5lib
import urllib
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches

document = Document()

url = "https://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&DEPA=0&Order=BESTMATCH&Description="
Remaining_url="&ignorear=0&N=-1&isNodeId=1"
product_name = 'Seagate 80GB 7200 RPM SATA 3.0Gb/s Internal Hard Drive (IMSourcing) Bare Drive'
p = document.add_paragraph("Product_name " +":"+"  "+product_name)

search_words = {'text': product_name}
search_url = urllib.parse.urlencode(search_words).split("=")[1]
product_url = url + search_url + Remaining_url
content = urlopen(product_url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html5lib")
print(soup.find_all("div", class_="list-wrap"))
```

I run the program its throwing empty list.How to fix it any one can give any solution.

Comment: We have found 0 items that match "Seagate 80GB 7200 RPM SATA 3.0Gb/s Internal Hard Drive (IMSourcing) Bare Drive" is what I see for your request.

Comment: No I tried lot of request to get data in this site.but i got some product details .its automatically start robot.so how to solve it. and how to request to solwly to use to scrape the data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is correct, the result list was empty.

```
        <div class="result-message">
         <p class="result-message-title">
          <span class="result-message-error">
           We have found 0 items that match "Seagate 80GB 7200 RPM SATA 3.0Gb/s Internal Hard Drive (IMSourcing) Bare Drive".
          </span>
         </p>
        </div>
```

You can pause between GET requests using [`sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep):

```
time.sleep(1.5)
```